# Conditional Validation in MVC using IValidatableObject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core-mvc, data-annotations

I have a scenario where I need to validate a view model differently under different contexts.  For example, certain fields are required if you are going to, say, Post a message but they are not needed if you just want to save a Draft.  Yet, there are still required fields for a Draft.  Therefore, I have inputs that require validation based on the scenario you are saving under.

I'm using IValidatableObject on supple input models since the static attributes don't seem to allow this.  I see there is the option to pass in data to the Validate method using the ValidationContext.Items property.  I can read that in the validation, but after searching through the source code for MVC, it doesn't look like there's a way to actually set that before you would do a TryUpdate, etc, to set the scenario you're validating under.

Am I missing something or is there another method I'm not seeing?

```
public IEnumerable<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
  ValidationLevel validationLevel;
  object validationLevelObject;
  if (validationContext.Items.TryGetValue("$" + nameof(ValidationLevel), out validationLevelObject))
  {
    validationLevel = (ValidationLevel)validationLevelObject;
  }
  else
  {
    validationLevel = ValidationLevel.Full;
  }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model/class that implemented the IValidatableObject, try doing something like this:

```
    ...

    public List<ValidationResult> ValidationResults { get; } = new List<ValidationResult>();

    public bool TryValidate(out List<ValidationResult> vResults)
    {
        vResults = ValidationResults;

        var context = new ValidationContext(this);
        Validate(context);

        var fieldValidations = new List<ValidationResult>();
        var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(context.ObjectInstance, context, fieldValidations,
            validateAllProperties: true);

        //Add any attribute validation errors to ValidationResults
        if (!isValid)
        {
            foreach (var validationResult in fieldValidations)
            {
                ValidationResults.Add(validationResult);
            }
        }

        //Add your custom validations
        if (!IsDraft() && Message.IsStringBlank())
        {
            ValidationResults.Add(new ValidationResult("Message cannot empty");
        }

        isValid = !ValidationResults.Any();
        return isValid;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (_isClassValidate) return new List<ValidationResult>();

        _isClassValidate = true;

        return ValidationResults;
    }
```